# html area map, black box appearing

Tags: html

I've been working on a homepage, using a single image as the background, which can be scrolled vertically. There are multiple fields on this image, on which you can click using the map tag. On firefox there's a black box appearing further down, or up, depending on what has ( or hasn't ? ) been loaded when opening the page. What could cause this?

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkecF.png)

[file for reproduction: docs_overview_desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WnsQ.jpg)

[file for reproduction: docs_overview_mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H5zC.jpg)

[file for reproduction: gh-pages_000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LKy4.jpg)

[file for reproduction: gh-pages_001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CuEn.jpg)

The full code used: https://pastebin.com/m9BPfqzp

```
            <div class="desktop">
            <img name="overview_desktop_img" src="docs/docs_overview_desktop.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" usemap="#desktop">
            <map name="desktop" id="desktop">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1028.5715,0,1371.4285,480" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="720,68.5715,960,411.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="720,480,960,822.857" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,720,342.857,960" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,1028.5715,480,1371.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="137.143,1440,480,1680" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="548.5715,1200,891.4285,1440" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="960,1200,1302.857,1440" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="548.5715,1508.5715,1028.5715,1851.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1097.143,1680,1440,1920" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="240,1920,720,2262.857" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="960,1988.5715,1440,2331.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1028.5715,2400,1371.4285,2640" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="240,2880,480,3222.857" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="548.5715,2880,891.4285,3360" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="960,2948.5715,1200,3291.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="960,2948.5715,1200,3291.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="137.143,3291.4285,480,3771.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_001.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="960,3771.4285,1302.857,4251.4285" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="720,4320,960,4662.857" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1028.5715,4320,1371.4285,4800" href="gh-pages/gh-pages_000.html">
            </map>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile">
            <img name="overview_mobile_img" src="docs/docs_overview_mobile.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="">
        </div>
```

Comment: I not 100% sure about this but there is lots of bug information about Firefox randomly placing black boxes throughout the page. I don't use the socials but apparently this happens a lot on Facebook. It could be possible that there is nothing at all wrong with your code. I did think perhaps you had a black html background that was somehow showing but can't see anything to indicate that.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob It's been a thought of mine aswell, so I'm guessing it'll be part of the project, until firefox is able to fix this issue...